# Login con privilegios de usuario

Tags: php, html, mysql, login

Realizo un login con privilegios es decir si es un administrador que lo redirija a otra pagina, pero tengo un problema con mi código ya que lo que necesito comparar es mi campo `username` `(username == administrador)` si es igual a administrador entonces que redirija a `index_admon.php` pero no lo hace no me deja entrar al sistema.

Agradezco su ayuda.

Estructura de la BD:

```
id   Primaria       
username
name    
email
password
profile_pic
is_active
```

Código `Login.php`:

```html
<?php
 session_start();

 if (isset($_POST['token']) && $_POST['token']!=='') {
   
 //Contiene las variables de configuracion para conectar a la base de datos
 include "../config/config.php";

 $email=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["email"],ENT_QUOTES)));
 $password=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["password"],ENT_QUOTES)));
 $username=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["username"],ENT_QUOTES)));

    $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM user WHERE email ='$email' OR username='$username' AND password = '$password'");
 
 

  if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
   

    $_SESSION['username'] = $row['admon'];
    header("location: ../index_admon.php");
    

  }else{
   $invalid=sha1(md5("contrasena y email invalido"));
   header("location: ../index.php?invalid=$invalid");
  }
 }else{
  header("location: ../");
 }

?>
```

Comment: una pregunta, ¿el campo username va a contener el tipo de usuario?, creo no esta bien, o al menos no lo hago así, yo tengo un campo especifico para el tipo de usuario de los sistemas, por otro lado, utilizo es un solo index y alli muestro la informacion que concierne a cada tipo de ususario, de igual manera hago con el menú, solo muestro las opciones que corresponde al usuario, deberías revisar eso

Answer (score 0):

Como te comente tienes algunos errores alli, o al menos así lo veo:

1.- La query esta filtrando o por email o por username, el problema de eso es que validas el tipo de usuario por username, así que si yo en tu sistema inicio un ataque colocando alli Admin, Administrador, etc, es posible que me deje pasar.

1.- El password validalo luego de la query, de esa manera puedes validar correctamente el hash, pues allí indica que no estas encriptando tu clave o las claves de los usuarios.

Luego de resolver eso y otras cositas, puedes ejecutar esto para enviar a los usuarios a su destino:

```
switch($row['tipouser']){
    case 'Administrador':
        //Index de administradores
        header('location:...');
    break;

    case 'Usuario':
        //Index de Usuarios
        header('location:...');
    break;

    case 'Otro':
        //Index de Otros
        header('location:...');
    break;
}
```